# Clear the selected value from android spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox, android-spinner

Once the check box is check then the spinner will be show and once the check box is unchecked then the spinner will be hidden. I have shown that combination in the below image.

[image]

I have achieved this using below code I have shown.

```
halfHalfCB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (halfHalfCB.isChecked()) {
                    extraDescriptionHalfSP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    extraDescriptionHalfSP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                  String extraDescriptionHalf = extraDescriptionHalfSP
//                          .getSelectedItem() != null ? extraDescriptionHalfSP
//                          .getSelectedItem().toString() : null;
//                          extraDescriptionHalf = null;
                }
            }

        });

        addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    String extraDescriptionHalf = extraDescriptionHalfSP
                            .getSelectedItem() != null ? extraDescriptionHalfSP
                            .getSelectedItem().toString() : null;
```

Actually my problem is once the check box is checked and then user select a value from spinner and then user unchecked the check box. I want to clear the selected value from the spinner (or make the selected value null). How can I do that? From my current code spinner carries the selected item.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do it like this:

```
  ...
  else {
                extraDescriptionHalfSP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                extraDescriptionHalfSP.setSelection(-1);
                textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove items from the spinner you can use :

```
myspinner.setAdapter(null);
```

Comment: @modabeckham how this going to work.. spinner will be still visible?

Comment: This code worked for me. No it hides. I'm using this code extraDescriptionHalfSP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     extraDescriptionHalfSP.setAdapter(null);

Comment: @utility I have made a mistake, when I hide the spinner after selecting a value it make the adapter null, when I open it back items doesn't load. vinitius has given a perfect answer. So I have to vote him. Sorry about that.

Comment: @modabeckham just showed an option ,happy that you got the right solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```